# Error: NVCC compiler not in $path

Tags: python, theano

I've got Theano working, and I've installed Cuda.

The nvcc compiler is in the windows path variable.

Yet, when I run theano, I get the following error:

> ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): nvcc compiler not found on $PATH. Check your nvcc installation and try again.

I'm not really sure what could be going on.  Could it be that theano is looking at a different "$PATH"?

Theanorc file:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu0
[nvcc]
fastmath = True
```

(I get the same error regardless of whether I include `[nvcc]`)

Comment: Please include your theanorc file

Answer (score 6):

Try add the following section in Thranorc file:
[cuda]
root = /usr/local/cuda-7.5

I encountered same issue and solved by add these 2 lines.